# Is it possible to build a custom auth payload with Firebase Simple Login?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase

I am building up a login module, and am quite happy with how it is working using $firebaseSimpleLogin.

I have email/password, twitter, and facebook logins working and even able to link them to a single user profile (so a user may have multiple access points for their convenience).

Now that I am building up my Security Rules in the firebase forge, I am needing different data in my auth payload than [simpleLogin provides](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rule-expressions/auth.html).

I've started reading about [custom token generators](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html), but from what I am understanding, I would need to write my own authentication handlers, essentially duplicating the 3rd-party authentications that simpleLogin provides.

Is there an easier way to add custom data to my auth payload after the simpleLogin succeeds?

Comment: What sort of custom data do you want to add?

Comment: I'd like to add a user "role", which would be from an entry in a user profile tree.  I might be able to do it with the RulesDataSnapshot, but I think having a custom auth payload would be much easier to manage given the scale of our application.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that uses $firebaseSimpleLogin for the password/facebook/twitter authentication and in its success callback, I use the [FirebaseTokenGenerator](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-js) to create my custom auth payload.